# Bash Script to find files

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems

Good day,
I've found an easy way to find files that have certain content, but I would like to create a bash script to do it quickier,

The script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIRECTORY=$(cd `dirname .` && pwd)
ARGUMENTS="'$@'"

echo find: $ARGUMENTS on $DIRECTORY
find $DIRECTORY -iname '*' | xargs grep $ARGUMENTS -sl
```

So if I write:

```
$ script.sh text
```

It should find in that directory files that contains 'text'

But when I execute this script it always fails, but the echo command shows exactly what I need, what's wrong with this script?

Thank you!

Luis

References: http://www.liamdelahunty.com/tips/linux_find_string_files.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are problems with quoting that will break in this script if either the current directory or the search pattern contains a space. The following is more simply, and fixes both issues:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec grep "$@" {} +
```

With the proper quoting of `$@`, you can even pass options to grep, such as `-i`.

```
./script -i "some text"
```

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, an elegant solution

Answer (score 2):

Try this version, with the following changes:

1.Use `$1` instead of `$@` unless you intend to run multiple find/grep to search for multiple patterns.

2.Use `find $DIR -type f` to find all files instead of `find $DIR -iname '*'`

3.Avoid piping by using the `-exec` command line option of `find`.

4.Do not single quote the command line arguments to your script, this was the main problem with the version you had. Your grep string had escaped single quotes `\'search_string\'`

```
#!/bin/bash
DIRECTORY=$(cd `dirname .` && pwd)
ARGUMENTS="$1"

echo find: $ARGUMENTS on $DIRECTORY
find $DIRECTORY . -type f -exec grep -sl "$ARGUMENTS"  {} \;
```

There is no point extracting all the command line arguments and passing it to `grep`. If you want to search for a string with spaces, pass the string within single quotes from the command line as follows:

```
/home/user/bin/test-find.sh 'i need to search this'
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just run the following?:

```
grep -R text .
```